# VNC menu bar color

Tags: vnc

I'm connecting from a windows 7 vnc 5.0.3 client to VNC server on Red Hat linux GNOME desktop. The menu bar has a strange pink & yellow color.
(When I change to KDE this dissapears)
Is there a way to solve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changed FullColour False -> True

[image]